# (How) can a matplotlib figure be made to respond to "zoom" navigation in one dimension only?

Tags: matplotlib

Matlab has a useful zoom mode triggered by `zoom xon`  or `zoom yon` whereby you can click-and-drag with the mouse to zoom in on data, but with only one dimension (x or y, respectively) changing.  Instead of an elastic box, the cursor changed into an elastic I-beam that allowed you to set the beginning and end of the range quite precisely.

Is there any way of getting a matplotlib figure to do the same thing?  Playing with the toolbar, and briefly looking into the code behind it, I only see a "zoom rect" mode.

I'm aware that you can approximate this effect by right-clicking-and-dragging in "pan" mode, while *trying* to ensure that your hand only moves in one dimension, but that can be quite frustratingly imprecise.  If there were a `zoom xon` equivalent, I would gladly use that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [interactive navigation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/navigation_toolbar.html#navigation-keyboard-shortcuts) lists among its shortcuts

- Constrain pan/zoom to ***x*** axis:   hold <kbd>x</kbd> when panning/zooming with mouse
- Constrain pan/zoom to ***y*** axis:   hold <kbd>y</kbd> when panning/zooming with mouse

Comment: Nice to know! But I cannot use it, because the anaconda/macOS backend for matplotlib doesn't ever allow a figure to be the focus of keyboard input.  The `x`'s just appear on the console....   Maybe I'll delve into the sources to see how that's implemented so I can replicate it programmatically.

Comment: Or you just don't use the macOS backend. There is nowadays little reason for not using the Qt backend, even on mac

Comment: Good call, thanks.  Actually with my anaconda python3 distro, only an upgrade of matplotlib from 2.x to 3.1 was required to unlock that feature—no backend tweaking necessary.   With my anaconda python2 distro I had to wage a dependency-installation campaign that culminated in me burning everything to the ground, reinstalling, and adding pyqt.  Now with `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('QtAgg');matplotlib.interactive(True);import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` even that works as you describe. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @jez! At the moment the QtAgg is not recognized in matplotlib, use `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')` instead.